# Management sistema for drivers

Tags: uber-api

I am developing a management system for drivers and I wonder if it is possible to connect to any api and be able to see earnings data, kilometers traveled etc.

Comment: Generally speaking, if there's an api, it was meant to be connected to. Whether or not _your_ app can connect, that's another question entirely. Some APIs are not for public consumption.

Comment: Sergio,  Where can I find out what are the payment api and if these are used for my purposes?